# How do I remove a key from an element object property

Tags: polymer

I have a Polymer 1.0 custom element which has a property called obj which is an object, say 
obj = { a: 1,
  b: 2}

How do I remove one of the keys?

I have tried this.set('obj.a', undefined)
and this.set('obj.a', null)

but result is {a: null (or undefined),
               b: 2}

where what I want is just to remove 'a' leaving {b:2}

is there a correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `delete`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Example:

```
let x = {a: 1, b: 2, '#sss': 3};

delete x.a;         // x is now {b: 2, '#sss': 3}
delete x['#sss'];   // x is now {b: 2}
```

Comment: @PhilGiggles are you sure `delete` is firing Polymer events? For me observers are not being updated.